# unfortunately app has been stopped while developing android app using cordova and jquery mobile

Tags: android, cordova

I am not sure what is causing this not runnig fine, When i run the app in my android emulator it shows error "unfortunately app has been stopped"

Any help is apprecieted.
My logCat error looks like this

```
03-29 10:25:32.717: E/Trace(779): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.parkingtracker/com.example.parkingtracker.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.parkingtracker.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.parkingtracker-1.apk
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2106)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.parkingtracker.MainActivity" on path: /data/app/com.example.parkingtracker-1.apk
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1054)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2097)
03-29 10:25:32.907: E/AndroidRuntime(779):  ... 11 more
```

My AndroidManifest.xml looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.parkingtracker"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<supports-screens 
    android:largeScreens="true" 
    android:normalScreens="true" 
    android:smallScreens="true" 
    android:resizeable="true" 
    android:anyDensity="true" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_LOCATION_EXTRA_COMMANDS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_CONTACTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BROADCAST_STICKY" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.parkingtracker.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: is MainActivity a public class declared in the package `com.example.parkingtracker` ?

Comment: yes..it is declared and it is show below

Comment: public class MainActivity extends DroidGap
    {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        System.out.println(Config.getStartUrl());
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")
    }
}

Comment: Please edit your question instead of putting so much code in a comment. This is quite unreadable...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who face the same problem i'm posting the solution

Problem:

After creating a new Android Project in Eclipse I included cordova jar in the build path and added my html page in assests/www folder and made corresponding changes in MainActivity.java file. But while running application in Android Emulator its showing an error "Unfortunately HelloWorldCordova App has stopped unexpectedly".

Solution: Please read my gist to find solution

https://gist.github.com/itsamiths/5276983

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be missing a class named MainActivity. Check your java class name and package name properly

Comment: Main Activity Class is 
    public class MainActivity extends DroidGap
    {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set by <content src="index.html" /> in config.xml
        System.out.println(Config.getStartUrl());
        super.loadUrl(Config.getStartUrl());
        //super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html")
    }
}